# Using SQL case statement to change the output for each employee and each date

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Using the following table how can I change the value to become 'in' when its the minimum value and 'out' when its the maximum while also changing the in-between values to become 'leave out' if its the first one after the 'in' but it's not the max and the record after it to become leave in also if its not the max.

```
code val       date                     val2
001 1           2018-08-08 00:00:00.000 NULL
001 2           2018-08-08 00:00:00.000 NULL
001 3           2018-08-08 00:00:00.000 NULL
001 4           2018-08-08 00:00:00.000 NULL
001 1           2018-08-09 00:00:00.000 NULL
001 2           2018-08-09 00:00:00.000 NULL
002 1           2018-08-09 00:00:00.000 NULL
002 2           2018-08-09 00:00:00.000 NULL
002 3           2018-08-09 00:00:00.000 NULL
002 4           2018-08-09 00:00:00.000 NULL
003 1           2018-08-09 00:00:00.000 NULL
003 2           2018-08-09 00:00:00.000 NULL
```

I have managed to change the minimum value but the maximum is changing only per date and note employee code.

Comment: I think desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*,
       (case when val = 1 then 'in'
             when val = max(val) over (partition by code) then 'out'
             else 'leave out'
        end)
from t;
```

If so, the logic can easily be incorporated into an update.